Chrome extension to load and show images on clicking on them
I need a Chrome extension with the following functionality:

Replace all images on a webpage with a placeholder.
Show an image (and only that image) when I click on that placeholder.

Ideally, those images should be blocked before fetching the page together with the resources, so that I would save traffic on downloading unneeded imags. However, the main feature for me is 'hiding-by-default/showing-on-click' rather than saving traffic, so it is okay to download all those unneded images anyway, just don't show them.

Here's a solution if it's you that won't see any images: In your Chrome, turn on the setting "Don't allow sites to show images" (chrome://settings/content/images?search=images)

That is not what the OP is about.
